# randomized quick sort base case not working (sometimes)

Tags: python, algorithm, sorting, quicksort

While implementing *quick sort* I thought that when there's two or three element in the arr there's no need to continue dividing the arr since if you just partitioned the pivot you will end up with a sorted array.
The problem is after adding the following `if` statement there was output looking cyclic

```
if e-s == 2 or e-s == 1: 
   partition(arr,s,e)
   return
```

without the if condition above the code works fine

```
import random

def quickSort(arr,s,e):
    if s >= e: return 
    if e-s == 2 or e-s == 1: 
        partition(arr,s,e)
        return    
    x = randPartition (arr,s,e)
    quickSort(arr,s,x-1)
    quickSort(arr,x+1,e)
        
def partition(arr,s,e):
    pivot = arr[s]
    x = s
    for i in range (s+1,e+1):
        if arr[i] < pivot :
            x+=1
            arr[x],arr[i]=arr[i],arr[x]
    arr[s],arr[x] = arr[x],arr[s]
    return x 

def randPartition(arr,s,e):
    x = random.randint(s,e)
    arr[x],arr[s] = arr[s],arr[x]
    return partition(arr,s,e)

arr = [1,5,0,3,-15,12,96,99,1500,-1500,66,120]
quickSort(arr,0,len(arr)-1)
print(arr)
```

```
output
[-1500, -15, 0, 1, 3, 12, 5, 66, 96, 99, 120, 1500]
[-1500, -15, 0, 1, 5, 3, 12, 66, 96, 120, 99, 1500]
[-1500, -15, 0, 1, 3, 5, 12, 66, 96, 99, 120, 1500]
[-1500, -15, 0, 1, 3, 5, 12, 66, 99, 96, 120, 1500]
[-1500, -15, 0, 1, 3, 5, 12, 66, 96, 99, 1500, 120]
[-1500, -15, 0, 1, 3, 5, 12, 66, 96, 120, 99, 1500]
[-1500, -15, 0, 1, 3, 5, 12, 66, 96, 99, 120, 1500]
[-1500, -15, 0, 1, 3, 5, 12, 66, 96, 99, 120, 1500]
[-1500, -15, 0, 1, 3, 5, 12, 66, 96, 99, 1500, 120]
[-1500, -15, 0, 3, 1, 5, 12, 66, 96, 99, 120, 1500]
[-1500, -15, 0, 1, 3, 5, 12, 66, 96, 99, 120, 1500]
[-1500, -15, 0, 1, 3, 5, 12, 66, 96, 99, 1500, 120]
[-1500, -15, 0, 1, 3, 5, 12, 66, 96, 99, 120, 1500]
[-1500, -15, 0, 1, 3, 5, 12, 66, 96, 99, 1500, 120]
[-1500, -15, 0, 1, 3, 5, 12, 66, 96, 99, 120, 1500]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### You are almost there! Just need to separate the 2-element and 3-element cases

You currently are handling *both* by a call to `partition`. In fact, for the two-element case you can just do a simple `if` that swaps them if they are the wrong way round.

```
import random

def quickSort(arr,s,e):
    if s >= e: 
        return 
    if e-s == 1:
        if arr[s] > arr[e]:
            arr[s], arr[e] = arr[e], arr[s]
        return
    if e-s == 2: 
        partition(arr,s,e)
        return    
    x = randPartition (arr,s,e)
    quickSort(arr,s,x-1)
    quickSort(arr,x+1,e)
        
def partition(arr,s,e):
    pivot = arr[s]
    x = s
    for i in range (s+1,e+1):
        if arr[i] < pivot:
            x+=1
            arr[x],arr[i]=arr[i],arr[x]
    arr[s],arr[x] = arr[x],arr[s]
    return x  

def randPartition(arr,s,e):
    x = random.randint(s,e)
    arr[x],arr[s] = arr[s],arr[x]
    return partition(arr,s,e)

arr = [1,5,0,3,-15,12,96,99,1500,-1500,66,120]
quickSort(arr,0,len(arr)-1)
print(arr)
```

#### Result

```
[-1500, -15, 0, 1, 3, 5, 12, 66, 96, 99, 120, 1500]
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that the single call to `partition` does not guarantee that the result is sorted. For instance, if the subarray (between `s` and `e`) consists of `[1, 3, 2]`, then `partition` will not make any changes (because `1` is the pivot and indeed `3` and `2` are both greater than it). Only if the pivot happens to get moved to the middle will the result be sorted.

If you want to deal with a length-3 array with only calls to `partition`, then call `partition` a second time if the pivot of the first call didn't arrive in the middle, and call it on the subarray that excludes that pivot:

```
    if e - s < 3:
        x = partition(arr, s, e)
        if e - s == 2 and x != s + 1:
            partition(arr, s + (x == s), e - (x == e))
        return
```